# Read a file and group its text

Tags: java, text, filereader

I have a file which contains some text and at the end a number. The file is like:

```
 to Polyxena. Achilles appears in the in the novel The Firebrand by Marion 
the firebrand   14852520
 fantasy novelist David Gemmell omic book hero Captain Marvel is endowed with the courage of Achilles, as well 
captain marvel  403585
 the city its central theme and 
corfu   45462
```

What I want is to group all the text till the number. For example:

```
" to Polyxena. Achilles appears in the in the novel The Firebrand by Marion the firebrand   14852520" 

" fantasy novelist David Gemmell omic book hero Captain Marvel is endowed with the courage of Achilles, as well captain marvel  403585"
```

I noticed that each group of text begins with white-space. However I have a difficulty how to group them. I coded this:

```
String line;
String s = " ";
char whiteSpace = s.charAt(0);

ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{   
    if (whiteSpace == line.charAt(0)){ //start of sentence
        lines.add(line);            
    }
}
in.close();
```

Comment: Actually you only add the lines with a white space at the front to the "lines "arraylist, right?. So eg. _the firebrand   14852520_ should not in the array right ? Maybe try it with an index. So all lines between two whitespaces are added to one index. Increase the index if a line starts with a white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow this algorithm:

- Create an empty buffer
- For each line:

  - Append to the buffer
  - If the line ends with a number:
  - Add the buffer to the list
  - Empty the buffer

Something like this:

```
String text = " to Polyxena. Achilles appears in the in the novel The Firebrand by Marion \n" +
        "the firebrand   14852520\n" +
        " fantasy novelist David Gemmell omic book hero Captain Marvel is endowed with the courage of Achilles, as well \n" +
        "captain marvel  403585\n" +
        " the city its central theme and \n" +
        "corfu   45462";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);

List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    buffer.append(line);
    if (line.matches(".*\\d+$")) {
        lines.add(buffer.toString());
        buffer.setLength(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works! great!  however, can you explain me plz what is `.*\\d+$` ?

Comment: It's a regular expression. `\\d+` means one or more digits, `$` means at the end of the file, and `.*` means any number of any character.